# long data to wide without a value in column

Tags: r, dplyr, long-integer, reshape, tidyr

I have a data let us say it is called df

```
Inspection  Error
111         A02
112         B02
122         D02
122         A02
```

I wish to have the data displayed in the following way;

```
Inspection  Error   Error
111         A02 
112         B02 
122         D02      A02
```

As you can see the "inspection" row of 122 is now transferred to columns with values D02 and A02. I tried spread function and cast, but the result is not close to what I want. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. 
Just an extra info - my inspection is numeric and Error as character. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a new column to count the values in each level of `Inspection`. Then you cast to wide using that new column:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

dat %>% group_by(Inspection) %>%
  arrange(Error) %>%
  mutate(counter = paste0("Error", 1:n())) %>%
  dcast(Inspection ~ counter, value.var="Error", fill="")

  Inspection Error1 Error2
1        111    A02       
2        112    B02       
3        122    A02    D02
```

Per @David Arenburg's comment, here's the `tidyr` version:

```
library(tidyr) 

dat %>% 
  group_by(Inspection) %>%
  arrange(Error) %>%
  mutate(counter = paste0("Error", 1:n())) %>%
  spread(counter, Error, fill = "")
```

Comment: Wow. thanks eipi10. It just made my day:) I knew that I had to mutate a new column just did not know what values it should contain. Thanks again

Comment: `spread(counter, Error, fill = "")` will also work (if `Error` is a character) as it seems like they are looking for `tidyr` solution.. And you probably could use `row_number()` here too.

Comment: I don't know David, I just made his day using `dcast` :).